List columns does not appear in search config after 2 days
I have created a new Content Type with custom columns.
Some of them must be indexed, so I need to link them to some RefinableString values.
But after 2 days I have created these columns, in the Search admin interface when I search for the column they do not show up.
Is there a way to force SharePoint being aware that those columns are already in place?
I'm completely stucked in this infinite waiting, could you please help?
Thank you

On-premises or Online?

Sorry, you're right: I'm on SharePoint online

Empty fields will not be processed by crawler in order to create crawled properties. Try to populate at least one of these and wait max 15 mins.

I know that I need to populate the list for the crawler to work properly, so 2 days ago I've also inserted some rows in my list (filling up every column), but nothing changed so far...I've never experieced a waiting so long...

You've never experienced because it's not usual :) I suppose you have searched them in crawled properties not in managed, right?

So have you the same experiencs? How long this wait could last? I've never experieced more than one day...Yes, crawled properties...

In my experience a new populated field take minutes to be crawled... which type of costum columns you have created?

tried to create columns of the following types:

site column of type single line of text
a column of type single line of text
site column of taxonomy type


Try to read here, maybe it will be useful link

Thank you for the article, for sure interesting, but it's all about managed properties names based on how you create a new column...nothing related to timing of them to show up or forcing the crawler in doing his job...

Only site columns are crawled, no "simple" list columns, you add site columns in site settings, then add the column in you list with "Add from existing site columns"

In my personal experience, a crawled property does not take more than 72 hours to be created, even if in most cases it is visible after a few minutes in the dedicated section of the site collection (/_layouts/15/listcrawledproperties.aspx?level=sitecol) or in the tenant level section (/_layouts/15/searchadmin/ta_listcrawledproperties.aspx?level=tenant).
I don't think it is possible to force the creation of a crawled (it wasn't even on-prem if I remember correctly) but you could try to set the entire site collection as "to be reindexed" by navigating to this link /_layouts/15/srchvis.aspx and clicking on "Reindex Site".
The only other thing that comes to mind is that there was some problem with the custom fields you created (internal names, strange characters, I don't know...) even if it seems difficult to me given the TEXT and Managed typology.
Other reference: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-find-the-correct-crawled-property-for-your-sharepoint-column/
At this link there is also a list of checks that you can do before opening a ticket to MS https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-crawled-properties-not-being/69ccb809-8095-4563-9aef-82caf87cc63d
Finally here is an article that explains how to check the logs for errors
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/07/get-search-crawl-log-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html
